# C# Linq get data if exists two records

Tags: c#, linq

I'm very bad right now in making queries but I'm trying to learn from my mistakes. I have three tables `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3`. From `Table1` I want to get all the records that have in `Table3` a row with Name `Attribute1` and value `F` **AND** another row with Name `Attribute2` and value `S`.

What I've tried is:

```
from i in entities.Table1.AsNoTracking().Where(i => (i.IsDeleted == false))
                    join se in entities.Table2.AsNoTracking() on i.Id equals se.SId
                    join set in entities.Table3.AsNoTracking().Where(i => (i.Name == "Attribute1" && i.Value.Contains("F"))
                                                                              && (i.Name == "Atrribute2" && i.Value.Contains("S")))
                                                                              on i.Id equals set.SId
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = i.Name,
                        Id = i.Id
                    };
```

but it doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use "OR"  .Where(i => (i.Name == "Attribute1" && i.Value.Contains("F"))
  ||  (i.Name == "Atrribute2" && i.Value.Contains("S")))

Comment: Is `Atrribute2` the correct spelling?

Comment: You should have Name Dana set to Yes and Diane set to No (for example). I think it should be something like if foreach field in Table1 exists Name Dana with value Yes and Name Diane with value No in Table 3 return the data from Table1

Comment: My point is that with your current code you are asking a single row "is your name `Attribute1` **and** is your name `Atrribute2`?" Clearly **both** can't be true.

Comment: @mjwills You are right :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
from i in entities.Table1.AsNoTracking().Where(i => (i.IsDeleted == false))
                    join se in entities.Table2.AsNoTracking() on i.Id equals se.SId
                    join set in entities.Table3.AsNoTracking().Where(i => (i.Name == "Attribute1" && i.Value.Contains("F")))
                                                                              on i.Id equals set.SId
                    join set2 in entities.Table3.AsNoTracking().Where(i => (i.Name == "Atrribute2" && i.Value.Contains("S")))
                                                                              on i.Id equals set2.SId
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = i.Name,
                        Id = i.Id
                    };
```

Comment: It needs to have both of the Attributes field, and for each attribute a certain value, not just one attribute

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seemed that I needed to make two joins with Table3